# laravel5 and htaccess redirect from http to https only one from many pages

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I'm using Laravel5. For example I have three pages in my project's menu: /site1, /site2, /site3 (relative)

In .htaccess i have rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so after enter in web browser "mypage.com" I have redirect to "http://www.mypage.com". Then my menu links after mouse hover has prefix http://

I need to redirect one of pages from menu (site1) as SSL to https.

So I need rule in htaccess, which redirect my enter in web browser www.example.com/site1 into https://www.example.com/site1 (but not redirect site2 and site3)

But then all my links in menu after mouse hover have prefix https://

So it's mean, after click in menu, I will browse all pages in SSL with https

How to configure htaccess to keep browse all pages with http with only one exception: site1 (where i need prefix https)

Thank you, kind regards

Comment: what is so bad in accessing all pages with https?

Comment: @Peh This is likely just not wanting to purchase another SSL cert and dedicated IP for the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.htaccess` to ensure https you can use a Middleware. First remove the redirection to https from your `.htaccess`.

#### 1. Secure Middleware

Add `Secure.php` into `app\Http\Middleware`

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
/**
 * Secure
 * Redirects any non-secure requests to their secure counterparts.
 * 
 * @param request The request object.
 * @param $next The next closure.
 * @return redirects to the secure counterpart of the requested uri.
*/
class Secure implements Middleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && env('production')) {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Assign Middleware to Routes

Append your Middleware to the list in `protected $routeMiddleware` within `App\Http\Kernel` Class.

And use it at the route you like to secure:

```php
Route::get('site1', ['middleware' => 'secure', function () {
    //
}]);
```

For more info see the docs: [Registering Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#registering-middleware)

#### Note

- The redirect is only working in production environment (if you have a certificate in development environment too you can omit the `&& env('production')` part).
- If you are using route annotations: Don't forget to `php artisan route:scan`.

#### Force a route NOT to use https

Make another Middleware class exactly like above steps 1 and 2 (e. g. call it `insecure` instead of `secure`). But change the `return` statement to the following:

```php
return Redirect::to(Request::getRequestUri(), 302, array(), false);
```